# как правильно сделать, чтобы при нажатии клавиши «пробел» выполнялся определенный код

Tags: javascript

Необходимо чтобы, при нажатии на пробел, задействовался этот код:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pause-button").click(function () {
        $("#pause-button").toggleClass("fas fa-play fa-xs").toggleClass("fas fa-pause fa-xs");
        var a = document.getElementById("video");
        a.paused ? a.play() : a.pause();
    });
});
```

Но только у меня отключены все кнопки(клава)
(onkeydown="return false;)

Comment: Что насчёт `keyup` и `keypress`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#pause-button").click(togglePlay);
});

$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
  if(e.keyCode === 32){
    togglePlay();
  }
});


function togglePlay() {
  const video = document.getElementById("video");

  $("#pause-button")
     .toggleClass("fas fa-play fa-xs")
     .toggleClass("fas fa-pause fa-xs");
  
  video.paused 
    ? video.play() 
    : video.pause();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
dument.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 32){
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#pause-button").click(function () {
                $("#pause-button").toggleClass("fas fa-play fa-xs").toggleClass("fas fa-pause fa-xs");
                var a = document.getElementById("video");
                a.paused ? a.play() : a.pause();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Эм.. Что простите?